# AngularJS Date Picker without use of moment or timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am using the following AngularJS Date Picker in my application:

https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

I am not setting any timezone (by default it takes the users timezone which is GMT+1 Europe/Berlin) and have a default configuration of the picker itself.

The selected time is getting stored in a Microsoft SQL Server table with a column of type DateTime. When the users select a date for example 13.01.2017 and stores this in the database, it get stored as in a format "2017-01-13 00:00:00". But when the user open the application again with the record he sees instead of the selected "13.01.2017"

```
"12.01.2017"
```

One day lower then selected. Do i need to set a fixed timezone like "Europe/Berlin" to always ensure that the selected date is returned from the db? Or is there any other AngularJS date picker which does not looks at the timezone instead takes plain the date which i give him and shows it?

**Update**

I have analyzed now more:

Given: Selected Date is **02.03.2015**.

This is what the Angular code sents to the sever:

[image]

This is what i have in the database:

[image]

This is what i get returned from the server:

[image]

And this is my implementation in HTML:

```
<input type="text" date-time format="DD.MM.YYYY" ng-model="myObj.Deadline" placeholder="Select Deadline ..." required />
```

I need only the date and need to ensure that i always get the selected date regardless of wich timezone the user has.

Comment: what is being returned from the DB, is it 2017-01-13 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing what i checked.

Comment: ok, so setting this value from scope in the datepicker leads to setting 1 day lower ?

Comment: Yes, thats the exact behavior.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you are using `DDMMYYYY` format and not `MMDDYYYY` format?

Comment: @STORM how do you set it from scope ?

Comment: @STORM do you use date-picker or date-time ?

Comment: @STORM working with date-time : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13348/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have analyzed more and put the result into my question. Hope this helps us to find the issue.

Comment: You should be storing your datetime as UTC. You can always go from UTC to local time but not always the other way around.

Comment: @RamblinRose: How can i do this? I have already set the format to DD.MM.YYYY.